# How do I hit all three delt heads all at once with only dumbbells and resistance bands available?

Tags: home-exercise, deltoids

I'm currently trying to sort of redesign my whole home workout. I did make some improvements. For example, I discovered that pushups, even with resistance bands, are an inferior exercise when triceps are concerned. I did lying dumbbell tricep extensions, as Jeff Cavaliere suggested in one video, and my triceps were sore like hell for several days (I'm not sure I had ever experienced it). Now, I want to have functional, strong delts that don't reach fatigue as easily as they do now. I currently do butterfly raises (again, I saw it in one of Jeff's videos). It seems to be a good exercise, but rear delts are kind of overlooked. Besides, there's some isometric stress on my biceps which is something I can put up with but not great for the reason below. I watched Jeff's few videos on delts, but nothing seems to check all the boxes which are (apart from activation of all three heads):

- only dumbbells or bands should be used;
- the exercise should not hit any of the leg or ab muscles (I train them separately, they should rest on my arm days)
- if possible, the exercise should not activate either triceps (e.g. through elbow extension), biceps, or forearms: I train them with specific exercises that I believe do the job in the best way possible (I do tricep extensions and alternating curls)
- bonus points for activating some of the back muscles too: I no longer have a "back day" so anything that hits either lats, or traps, or rhomboids, or spinal erectors to boot would be great (I don't have a horizontal bar!)

Comment: Barbell Medicine and Stronger By Science are going to be far more valuable resources for training information than Jeff. It really is not good content. He makes up words, doesn’t understand basic science, and sells you nonsense that looks and sounds cool so you’ll keep coming to him because he’s cool, which is probably why you’re having so many questions about his stuff.

Comment: Is there really a need to hit these very different muscles with a single exercise? You don't train triceps and biceps in a single exercise, why would you try to do that with other opposing muscles like the anterior and posterior deltoid?

Comment: Renaissance Periodization has some great resources on delts development, I've been following their side delts program myself for a few months and seeing good results.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov well, he claims to be a physical therapist and also occasionally references scientific publications. I like it

Answer (score 1):

#### Why?

Your criteria seem highly unusual. In particular, your request that this be one exercise seems to ignore basic anatomy. The posterior and anterior deltoids *do the opposite thing*. So hitting them at the same time with one movement with comparable intensity is impossible. Just do dumbbell rows or reverse flies, lateral raises, and front raises. These are very low fatigue movements that shouldn't take more than a few minutes to deliver a good stimulus to all three heads of the deltoid.

Comment: Jeff said dumbell swimmers hit all three heads so, I guess, it's possible. The problem is I don't have a bench (any more)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Then just go swimming. Notice what I said was impossible: *comparable intensity*. The load, set, and rep scheme appropriate for these muscles isn’t a priori the same. You should do different exercises for each, selecting load and reps appropriately for each one.

Comment: What about halo?